# ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing module django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddlewaredjango.middleware.clickjacking:

Tags: django, cloud, openshift

I am trying first time to deploy the app on openshift. The code is using Python 2.7, Django 1.6, MySQL Server 5.6.
I have got the cloned default code on C:\Users\welcome\resume\wsgi\openshift path.

Now, as per https://www.openshift.com/developers/deploying-and-building-applications link, first we need to run our code locally. After that we can push the code to openshift.

From my understanding, we need to add our code files to this folder, and make the suitable changes in the settings.py, setup.py etc as per the requirement.

NOTE: I have not done any changes in wsgi.py file

While trying to run the code locally, I am encountering the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\handlers.py", l
ine 67, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 187, i
n __call__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 47, in
 load_middleware
    mw_class = import_by_path(middleware_path)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 26,
in import_by_path
    sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 21,
in import_by_path
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py", line 40, in im
port_module
    __import__(name)
ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing module django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCa
cheMiddlewaredjango.middleware.clickjacking: "No module named FetchFromCacheMidd
lewaredjango.middleware.clickjacking"
[06/Aug/2014 12:13:33] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 59
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\handlers.py", l
ine 67, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 187, i
n __call__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 47, in
 load_middleware
    mw_class = import_by_path(middleware_path)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 26,
in import_by_path
    sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 21,
in import_by_path
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py", line 40, in im
port_module
    __import__(name)
ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing module django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCa
cheMiddlewaredjango.middleware.clickjacking: "No module named FetchFromCacheMidd
lewaredjango.middleware.clickjacking"
```

My Settings.py is :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Django settings for OpenShift project.
import imp, os
from django.middleware.clickjacking import XFrameOptionsMiddleware
from django.middleware.common import CommonMiddleware


ON_OPENSHIFT = False
if os.environ.has_key('OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR'):
    ON_OPENSHIFT = True

PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
if ON_OPENSHIFT:
    DEBUG = bool(os.environ.get('DEBUG', False))
    if DEBUG:
        print("WARNING: The DEBUG environment is set to True.")
else:
    DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@example.com'),
)
MANAGERS = ADMINS

if ON_OPENSHIFT:
    # os.environ['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_*'] variables can be used with databases created
    # with rhc cartridge add (see /README in this git repo)
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',  # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
            'NAME': os.path.join(os.environ['OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR'], 'sqlite3.db'),  # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
            'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
            'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
            'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
            'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
        }
    }
else:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',  # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
            'NAME': os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'sqlite3.db'),  # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
            'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
            'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
            'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
            'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
        }
    }


TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale
USE_L10N = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.environ.get('OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR', '')

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = ''

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, '..', 'static')

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# URL prefix for admin static files -- CSS, JavaScript and images.
# Make sure to use a trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://foo.com/static/admin/", "/static/admin/".
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    #'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make a dictionary of default keys
default_keys = { 'SECRET_KEY': 'vm4rl5*ymb@2&d_(gc$gb-^twq9w(u69hi--%$5xrh!xk(t%hw' }

# Replace default keys with dynamic values if we are in OpenShift
use_keys = default_keys
if ON_OPENSHIFT:
    imp.find_module('openshiftlibs')
    import openshiftlibs
    use_keys = openshiftlibs.openshift_secure(default_keys)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = use_keys['SECRET_KEY']

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    #'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',

'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddlewaredjango.middleware.clickjacking',
    )

ROOT_URLCONF = 'openshift.urls'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'templates'),
)


INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'openshift',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)


LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

Please tell where am i going wrong. Also, if possible guide on as to where to make changes and in which files and where to exactly copy the code.

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten a "," in your settings after "django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware"

As for what to copy and what files to modify, django documentation is superb and well detailed in nearly every little aspect of the framework:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/

After your edit:

This:

```
 'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddlewaredjango.middleware.clickjacking',
```

Should be:

```
  'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.clickjacking',
```

In your MIDDLEWARE settings

Comment: Thanks for reply ! I have checked "," is present. And I want to know editing of files in terms of openshift. As i said earlier, first we need to run our code locally. After that we can push the code to openshift. For this purpose what and how to edit and where to put files, I would like to know.

Comment: There is no proper tutorial in terms of how to edit code locally in that openshift cloned folder of code.

Comment: What to edit and what to do is clearly documented, if you are not understanding what each file does, you need to read the official documentation.

Comment: Obviously you need a vanilla settings file for your dev environment, working on a django application does not require you clone the remote server settings as well.

Comment: Any link would you suggest ? I don't know which and all settings or changes are required. Can I refer http://www.webforefront.com/django/configuredjangosettings.html  link?